# How to find image current source in html using Python

Tags: python, html

when extracting image from a website I use below command to get the URL:

```
image = soup.findAll('img')

image_link = image["src"]
```

But as the picture shows there is not a compelite link to save the image. Now my question is that what is this 'current source' showed on the picture and how I can extract the link from there?

[image]

Comment: `image_link = website_url + image["src"]` ?

Comment: thanks. could you please let me know how I can extract the base URL?

Comment: how do you fetch the HTML that you give to beautifulsoup ? Can you [edit] your post and share your code ?

Comment: In fact `image` is a an iterable, of ALL the img of the page, you can't just ask the source, check the answers

Comment: `/` at the src start is shorthand for “same domain as the page”.  Like @azro said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`soup.findAll()` returns a list of elements. Iterate over the "image" variable then access the "src" attribute on it.

If need to resolve relative URLs then need to call `requests.compat.urljoin(url, src)` on the image src value.

Try something like this:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# sample base url for testing
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

for img in soup.findAll('img'):
 src = img.get("src")
 if src:
   # resolve any relative urls to absolute urls using base URL
   src = requests.compat.urljoin(url, src)
   print(">>", src)
```

**Output:**

```
...
>> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:CentralAutoLogin/start?type=1x1
>> https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/footer/wikimedia-button.png
```

Without resolving relative urls in example above, the URL would be instead "/static/images/footer/wikimedia-button.png".

Answer (score 0):

In your case u can scrap images like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.sfmta.com/getting-around/drive-park/how-avoid-parking-tickets'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
for image in soup.find_all('img'):
    image_link = requests.compat.urljoin(url, image.get('src'))
    print(image_link)
```

OUTPUT:

```
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/all/themes/clients-theme/logo.png
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/default/files/imce-images/repair-40cd8d7db439deac706e161cd89ea3cc.jpg
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/default/files/imce-images/repair-a30c0bf7f9e9f1fcf5a4c6b69548c46b.jpg
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/default/files/imce-images/repair-cca5688579bf809ecb49daed5fab030a.jpg
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/default/files/imce-images/repair-8c6467ecb4673775240576524e4c5bc6.jpg
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/default/files/imce-images/repair-02709e2cecd6edde21a728562995764f.jpg
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/default/files/imce-images/repair-86826c5eeae51535f527f5a1a56a80fb.jpg
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/default/files/imce-images/repair-db285d8e0abc5e28e53f75a1a99d4a0b.jpg
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/default/files/imce-images/repair-73faffef0e5f0f36e0295e573dea1381.jpg
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/default/files/imce-images/repair-4eb40baaa405c6cb3e8379d5693c2941.jpg
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/default/files/imce-images/repair-f8fdee3388b83ec5eac01ff7c93a923e.jpg
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/all/themes/clients-theme/images/icons/application-pdf.png
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/all/themes/clients-theme/images/icons/application-pdf.png
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/all/themes/clients-theme/images/icons/application-pdf.png
https://www.sfmta.com/sites/all/themes/clients-theme/images/icons/application-pdf.png
```

But i recommend specify body class like **field-body** in soup, or check if link contains **imce-images**