# Python requests gives image src as relative path instead of absolute path

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, src, onerror

In the picture below I have the link of the image as src.

[image: src of an image in html]

but when using BeautifulSoup I got this output:

```
image['src']
assets/images/content/TUL_5890.jpg
```

Could you please let me know how to extract the image link in such a case?
I think that is because of the `onerror` in the code. but I don't know how to fix it .

Comment: can you share the page url please?

Comment: https://www.pexco.com/traffic/products/pedestrian-safety-products/in-street-pedestrian-crosswalk-signs/

Comment: Do you want the link of all images or just the main image I see on the page?

Comment: I want the links of all images on this website.

Comment: Hey Fateme, can you try my answer and let me know if it works for you'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see response html present in `soup`,

```
<a class="img-wrapper fancybox" data-caption="Pedestrian Crosswalk Sign" data-fancybox="group" href="assets/images/content/street_view_1a.jpg">
<img alt="Pedestrian Crosswalk Sign" src="assets/images/content/street_view_1a.jpg"/>
```

it does not have the entire path as you see in chrome which is probably added by your browser. Hence you were not getting the full path. You will have to extract the tag src and concat it with  the FQDN.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.pexco.com/traffic/products/pedestrian-safety-products/in-street-pedestrian-crosswalk-signs/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
for imgTag in soup.find_all('img'):
    img_src = imgTag['src']
    if ('assets' in img_src):
        print('https://www.pexco.com/' + img_src)
    else:
        print(img_src)
```

This gives us :

```
https://www.webtraxs.com/webtraxs.php?id=pexco&st=img
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/template/pexco-logo-dark.svg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/banners/bg-banner-traffic-desktop.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/TUL_5890.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/Davidson_STOP_4_Ped_Sign_Atlanta_012309.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/P0000689.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/street_view_1a.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/street_view_2a.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/TUL_5890.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/Davidson_STOP_4_Ped_Sign_Atlanta_012309.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/P0000689.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/street_view_1a.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/street_view_2a.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/CADdetails_Microsite_Button.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/template/pexco-logo-dark.svg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/template/fb-icon.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/template/LI-icon.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/template/YT-icon.jpg
https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=2856522&fmt=gif
```

**EDIT :**

As discussed with OP, she needs a solution that directly returns her the full url. Selenium can be used in this case.

Please try the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" # PUT YOUR CHROME PATH HERE
s = Service(chrome_path)

url = 'https://www.pexco.com/traffic/products/pedestrian-safety-products/in-street-pedestrian-crosswalk-signs/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(url)

images = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
for image in images:
    print(image.get_attribute('src'))
```

which gives us the expected output :

```
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/template/pexco-logo-dark.svg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/banners/bg-banner-traffic-desktop.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/TUL_5890.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/Davidson_STOP_4_Ped_Sign_Atlanta_012309.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/P0000689.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/street_view_1a.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/street_view_2a.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/TUL_5890.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/Davidson_STOP_4_Ped_Sign_Atlanta_012309.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/P0000689.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/street_view_1a.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/street_view_2a.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/content/CADdetails_Microsite_Button.jpg
https://www.pexco.com/assets/images/template/pexco-logo-dark.svg
https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_42x16dp.png
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/template/fb-icon.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/template/LI-icon.jpg
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/www.pexco.com/assets/images/template/YT-icon.jpg
https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/translate_24dp.png
https://marvel-b1-cdn.bc0a.com/f00000000266812/cdn1.thelivechatsoftware.com/assets/interchanges/pexco.com/resources/pexco_2021-11-18.03-09-45.png
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what you did is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72955624/how-to-find-image-current-source-in-html-using-python .

Comment: So its kind of duplicate question, as I said BS4 cannot do that, because the response itself did not receive the full path. You will have to use selenium for this

Comment: It does not work in my problem. my problem is how to get the src itself when there is an onerror on HTML code. Which means when the page is loaded the value of src would be whatever the onerror says.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: What do you mean by oneerror

Comment: oneerror is something that is dynamically added to the html, that's the reason its not coming with response

Comment: onerror is in the picture I attached to my question. it is in the img tag.

Comment: yes that onerror attribute is dynamic and does not come with response

Comment: yes exactly. so now you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: yes as I said, use selenium

Comment: let me know if you need selenium solution

Comment: yes sure that would be great. thanks

Comment: do you know how to setup your environment for selenium?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: if you have any suggestions I would appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: @FatemeNazari As I see that you already have setup selenium in your environment, I have updated my code using selenium. Please check it out